# What is the approximate price of a McDonnell Douglas MD-80 series aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-purchase, md-80

Does anyone know the approximate price of an MD-83/87 aircraft manufactured between 1990 and 2000?

Comment: You're looking for purchase price only, not concerned about operating or maintenance costs, or repairs likely to be needed on a 20-30 year old airframe (probably including new/rebuilt engines if the airframe has been standing in a boneyard)?

Comment: Prices on any aircraft can vary widely based on hours, configuration, included documentation, service history, and even current location. Can you provide us some more parameters?

Comment: Looking at the edit history, I'm not sure why this was closed with "needs focus" as the reason. There's only one question. It may still be off topic, as a price request, but not because there are too many questions. Or am I missing something?